# How to obtain certificate issuer thumbprint?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-service-fabric

I'm currently attempting to deploy a Service Fabric cluster using the instructions provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-create-cluster-using-cert-cn). I've successfully created a certificate using Let's Encrypt and am able to successfully handle all the instructions except for obtaining the certificateIssuerThumbprint value, as indicated as required in the parameters file at the top of [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-create-cluster-using-cert-cn#download-and-update-a-sample-template).

Looking at the certificate details in my Certificate Manager, I don't see a field providing this value. I read through the [Chain of Trust](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) page for Let's Encrypt on which I'd expect to find such a value, but I'm not seeing it.

How would I go about looking up what this certificate issuer thumbprint value is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mperian's answer is absolutely spot-on if the certificate lives in an Azure Key Vault.

In my case, the certificates are installed to the stores on the various machines. Building on their excellent answer, here's the Powershell to do the same locally without use of Azure Key Vault.

```
$thumbprint = ""
$store = "My"

$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path "Cert:\LocalMachine\$store" | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -match $thumbprint}
$certChain = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain]::new()
$certChain.Build($cert)
$certIssuerThumbprint = ($certChain.ChainElements.Certificate | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq $cert.Issuer}).Thumbprint
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vault -SecretName $secretName -Version $version
$certBytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($secret.SecretValueText)
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certBytes, $null, 'Exportable')

$certChain = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain]::new()
$certChain.Build($cert)

$certificateIssuerThumbprint = ($certChain.ChainElements.Certificate | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq $cert.Issuer}).Thumbprint
```

Comment: Having just attempted this, `SecretValueText` isn't a property on the Secret value anymore. Rather, to get the secret, the -AsPlainText parameter on Get-AzKeyVaultSecret will return it (and only it) in the response.

Answer (score 2):

I'm far from an expert on certificates, but here's what I think needs to be done:

- In certificate manager, if you simply double click and open the certificate > Certification Path tab, you should see your certificate at the bottom (as a leaf node), and in the Details tab you will see your certificate's thumbprint
- There should be a certificate above your certificate - I believe this is the issuer certificate. If you double click that issuer certificate > Details, I think that's the thumbprint you need

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to see that value after you upload it to Keyvault using the script in the link you provided

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-create-cluster-using-cert-cn#upload-the-certificate-to-a-key-vault

```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force

$SubscriptionId  =  "<subscription ID>"

# Sign in to your Azure account and select your subscription
Login-AzAccount -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

$region = "southcentralus"
$KeyVaultResourceGroupName  = "mykeyvaultgroup"
$VaultName = "mykeyvault"
$certFilename = "C:\users\sfuser\myclustercert.pfx"
$certname = "myclustercert"
$Password  = "P@ssw0rd!123"

# Create new Resource Group 
New-AzResourceGroup -Name $KeyVaultResourceGroupName -Location $region

# Create the new key vault
$newKeyVault = New-AzKeyVault -VaultName $VaultName -ResourceGroupName $KeyVaultResourceGroupName -Location $region -EnabledForDeployment 
$resourceId = $newKeyVault.ResourceId 

# Add the certificate to the key vault.
$PasswordSec = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$KVSecret = Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vaultName -Name $certName  -FilePath $certFilename -Password $PasswordSec

$CertificateThumbprint = $KVSecret.Thumbprint
$CertificateURL = $KVSecret.SecretId
$SourceVault = $resourceId
$CommName    = $KVSecret.Certificate.SubjectName.Name

Write-Host "CertificateThumbprint    :"  $CertificateThumbprint
Write-Host "CertificateURL           :"  $CertificateURL
Write-Host "SourceVault              :"  $SourceVault
Write-Host "Common Name              :"  $CommName
```

Comment: While the thumbprint is definitely necessary, my question is rather about the issuer thumbprint, which doesn't seem to be as accessible.

Answer (score -2):

From [Create an SF cluster using certificates declared by CN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-create-cluster-using-cert-cn):

"Note

The 'certificateIssuerThumbprint' field allows specifying the expected issuers of certificates with a given subject common name. This field accepts a comma-separated enumeration of SHA1 thumbprints. Note this is a strengthening of the certificate validation - in the case when the issuer is not specified or empty, the certificate will be accepted for authentication if its chain can be built, and ends up in a root trusted by the validator. If the issuer is specified, the certificate will be accepted if the thumbprint of its direct issuer matches any of the values specified in this field - irrespective of whether the root is trusted or not. Please note that a PKI may use different certification authorities to issue certificates for the same subject, and so it is important to specify all expected issuer thumbprints for a given subject.

Specifying the issuer is considered a best practice; while omitting it will continue to work - for certificates chaining up to a trusted root - this behavior has limitations and may be phased out in the near future. Also note that clusters deployed in Azure, and secured with X509 certificates issued by a private PKI and declared by subject may not be able to be validated by the Azure Service Fabric service (for cluster-to-service communication), if the PKI's Certificate Policy is not discoverable, available and accessible."

Note that upon renewing (or re-keying) a certificate, the issuer may well change. A PKI would typically publish all its active issuers in a Certification Practice Statement (CPS) ([here](https://letsencrypt.org/documents/isrg-cps-v2.7/) is LetsEncrypt's - unfortunately it doesn't seem to list the issuer certificates.)

If you're internal to Microsoft, you would probably know which API to use to retrieve authorized issuers; if you aren't, please contact the PKI of your choice for guidance.

Comment: This is a fine answer, but not to my question. Having read the same documentation, I understand the "why", but my question quite simply is "how" to get that thumbprint value (ideally programmatically).